# PDO insert query won't work

Tags: php, pdo

My PDO query won't work. This is my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Rally is our passion">
    <meta name="author" content="Robin Rosiers">

    <title>Sponsors - RPR Admin</title>

    <?php require_once ('include/core.php'); ?>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./img/favicon.ico">

    <!-- Add custom CSS here -->
    <link href="css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Page Specific CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.4.3.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="wrapper">

      <!-- Sidebar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php" alt="Rallypodium & Reporting" title="Rallypodium & Reporting">RPR - Administration Panel</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
            <li><a href="home.php"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="news.php"><i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i> Nieuws</a></li>
            <li><a href="fotos.php"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i> Foto's</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages.php"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Pagina's</a></li>
            <li><a href="editpages.php"><i class="fa fa-font"></i> Bewerk pagina's</a></li>
            <li><a href="meldingen.php"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> Melding(en)</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="sponsors.php"><i class="fa fa-money"></i> Sponsors</a></li>
            <li><a href="settings.php"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i> Instellingen</a></li>
            <li><a href="accsettings.php"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Account instellingen</a></li>
            <li><a href="addadmin.php"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Administrator toevoegen</a></li>
          </ul>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-user">
            <li class="dropdown user-dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> {Gebruikersnaam} <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="accsettings.php"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i> Instellingen</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Log uit</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </nav>

      <div id="page-wrapper">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1>Sponsors<small><br></small></h1>
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
              <li class="active"><i class="fa fa-money"></i> Sponsors</li>
            </ol>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.row -->

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Sponsor toevoegen</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body" style="max-height:600px; overflow:auto">
                 <!-- Content/script hier om een sponsor te adden. --> 
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST") {
                 $naam = $db->quote($_POST['naam']);
                 $site = $db->quote($_POST['site']);
                 $img = $db->quote($_POST['img']);
                 $opbrengst = $db->quote($_POST['opbrengst']);
                 $duur = $db->quote($_POST['duur']);

                 $sql = " INSERT INTO sponsors (naam, site, img, opbrengst, duur) VALUES ('".$naam.", ".$site.", ".$img.", ".$opbrengst.", ".$duur."')";
                 }
?>

                 <center>

                  <form action="?ok" method="post">
                  Sponsor naam: <input name="naam" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Naam..." style="width:auto;"><br>
                  Site (url) <input name="site" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="http://" style="width:auto;"><br>
                  Sponsor image (url) <input name="img" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="vb http://i.imgur.com/" style="width:auto;"><br>
                  Opbrengst: &euro; <input name="opbrengst" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="opbrengst" style="width:auto;"> /maand<br>

                  <div class="form-group">
                <label>Duur:</label>
                <select name="duur" class="form-control" style="width:auto;">
                  <option>1 maand</option>
                  <option>2 maanden</option>
                  <option>3 maanden</option>
                  <option>4 maanden</option>
                  <option>5 maanden</option>
                  <option>6 maanden</option>
                  <option>7 maanden</option>
                  <option>8 maanden</option>
                  <option>9 maanden</option>
                  <option>10 maanden</option>
                  <option>11 maanden</option>
                  <option>1 jaar</option>
                </select>
              </div>

                  <button type="submit" class="btn">Opslaan</button>
                  </form>

                 </center>              

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.row -->

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> Sponsor lijst</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">



                <?php

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM sponsors ORDER BY id";
                $results = $db->query($sql);

                foreach($results as $row)
                {
                    echo '<div class="alert alert-info">';
                    echo '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true" alt="verwijder de sponsor." title="verwijder de sponsor.">&times;</button>';
                    echo '<p>Naam: ';
                    echo $row['naam'];
                    echo ' <i class="fa fa-tag"></i> </p>';
                    echo '<p>Opbrengst: ';
                    echo $row['opbrengst'];
                    echo ' <i class="fa fa-money"></i> </p>';
                    echo '</div>';
                }

                ?>


              </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.row -->

      </div><!-- /#page-wrapper -->

    </div><!-- /#wrapper -->

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <!-- Page Specific Plugins -->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/morris/chart-data-morris.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tablesorter/tables.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

It is very wired. The select code works fine, but the insert query doesn't. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Debug this simply with `echo $sql;` You will find that you have single quotes only before the first and after the last variable in the `VALUES ()` list.

Comment: This is easily avoidable if you start learning to use prepared statements in PDO.  [I recommend this tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assigned the INSERT query string to a var, but didn't execute `$db->query($sql);` on it.

After

```
$sql = " INSERT INTO sponsors (naam, site, img, opbrengst, duur) VALUES ('".$naam.", ".$site.", ".$img.", ".$opbrengst.", ".$duur."')";
```

add

```
$db->query($sql);
```

Comment: Well spotted, but all the variables are incorrectly quoted too.

Comment: When i insert that code, i get a huge error when i press the insert button: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'qqqq', 'qqqqqq', 'qqqqq', 'qqqqq', '1 maand'')' at line 1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\adminpanel\sponsors.php:99 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\adminpanel\sponsors.php(99): PDO->query(' INSERT INTO sp...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\adminpanel\sponsors.php on line 99

Comment: @user3290259 As Michael pointed out, that error is due to the quotes in the query string being incorrect. You have an extra one before the first value and another after the last value.

Comment: indeed, my database looks like this: http://prntscr.com/2r0rpt Nothing  else... So if i'm doing my id automatic, the query must work?

Comment: @Advil That's not the problem. Take a look at http://pastebin.com/kz9amc0z and turn off wrapping (2nd icon just above the code).

Comment: Use try catch blocks to throw exceptions to the display. That will help you figure out many problems.

Answer (score 0):

you need tell PDO to rise error

```
setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

after that you can easily catch your problem .i wish

Comment: that line is alredy in my config.